# Controlling margins of Android Chronometer

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, chronometer

I have a layout with a Chronometer between 2 TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feed_current"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/current"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/feed_last_and_current"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/feed_last"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="0dp" />

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/feed_chronometer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="@color/panel_text"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/feed_current"
    android:layout_below="@id/feed_current"
    android:padding="0dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feed_action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_below="@+id/feed_detail"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/feed_chronometer"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/feed_chronometer" />
```

I've tried everything but Chronometer seems to create a margin between it and its surroundings.

[image: Chronometer and surroundings]
Do you have any idea how to remove those gap?

Thanks

Comment: what is the parent layout? you have `layout_alignTop="@+id/feed_last"` but you don't have a feed_last here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have negative margins for your items.

so for your bottom TextView you can have `layout_marginTop="-25"` or whatever margin is needed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about using negative margin values.